# How to solve this error when running MapReduce application?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

I'm really new to MapReduce and currently struggling with a MapReduce exercise. I'm given a really big dataset of U.S. patents granted between January 1963 and December 1999 that looks something like this:

```
"PATENT","GYEAR","GDATE","APPYEAR","COUNTRY","POSTATE","ASSIGNEE","ASSCODE","CLAIMS","NCLASS","CAT","SUBCAT","CMADE","CRECEIVE","RATIOCIT","GENERAL","ORIGINAL","FWDAPLAG","BCKGTLAG","SELFCTUB","SELFCTLB","SECDUPBD","SECDLWBD"
3070801,1963,1096,,"BE","",,1,,269,6,69,,1,,0,,,,,,,
3070802,1963,1096,,"US","TX",,1,,2,6,63,,0,,,,,,,,,
3695459,1972,4659,1970,"BE","",225495,3,,414,5,51,,2,,0.5,,16.5,,,,0,0
3695460,1972,4659,1970,"IT","",,1,,414,5,51,,1,,0,,28,,,,,
3866063,1975,5520,1973,"US","CA",188385,2,5,327,4,41,7,11,1,0.7438,0.4082,10.8182,5,0,0,0,0
3866064,1975,5520,1973,"US","FL",242085,2,10,327,4,41,5,11,1,0.314,0,10.9091,3.6,0,0,0,0
4548215,1985,9426,1983,"DE","",243670,3,25,131,6,61,2,7,1,0.2449,0,5.8571,19.5,0,0,0,0
4548216,1985,9426,1982,"GB","",382615,3,7,131,6,61,10,3,0.6,0,0.2778,5,20,0.5,0.2,0,0
...
```

These are the meanings of some attributes:
[image]

I need to implement a MapReduce Java class (which includes a Partitioner) to compute the average number of claims per patent grouped by country since 1975. The Partitioner sorts the results into two groups: The result for AU needs to be in the 1st group & those for other countries in the 2nd group. I will then need to show the result for AU using the Hadoop command.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class AvgClaimNumbersPerPatentByCountry extends Configured implements Tool {
    
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Avg Claims/Patent by Country since 1975"); 
        job.setJarByClass(AvgClaimNumbersPerPatentByCountry.class); 
        job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class); //the Mapper class 
        job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class); //the Reducer class 
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class); 
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class); //the Combiner class
        job.setPartitionerClass(MyPartitioner.class); //the Partitioner class
        
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new AvgClaimNumbersPerPatentByCountry(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private Text countryAsKey = new Text();
        private IntWritable claimsAsValue = new IntWritable(1);
        
        //map() function vvv
        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            if (line.contains("PATENT")) {
                return; //skip the first line
            }
            else {
                String[] patentData = line.split(",");
                countryAsKey.set(patentData[4]);
                if (Integer.parseInt(patentData[1]) >= 1975) {
                    claimsAsValue.set(Integer.parseInt(patentData[8]));
                }
            }
            context.write(countryAsKey, claimsAsValue);     
        }
        //map() function ^^^
    }
    
    public static class MyPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, IntWritable> {
        //getPartition() function vvv
        public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int numReduceTasks) {
            String country = key.toString();
            if (country.toLowerCase().matches("AU")) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        //getPartition() function ^^^
        
    }

    public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, FloatWritable> {
        //reduce() function vvv
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text countryKey, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int totalClaimsOfCountry = 0;
            int totalPatentsOfCountry = 0;
            FloatWritable avgClaim = new FloatWritable();

            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                totalClaimsOfCountry += value.get();
                totalPatentsOfCountry += 1;
            }
            avgClaim.set(calculateAvgClaimPerPatent(totalClaimsOfCountry, totalPatentsOfCountry));

            context.write(countryKey, avgClaim);
        }
        //reduce() function ^^^

        public float calculateAvgClaimPerPatent(int totalClaims, int totalPatents) {
            float avg = (float)totalClaims / totalPatents;
            return avg;
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the MapReduce application in Hadoop, I got this error:

```
21/08/19 01:18:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1629275188478_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
```

I understand that there are mismatched values in the code (I passed in FloatWritable while the system expected IntWritable) but I'm not sure how to fix this. I would really appreciate any ideas and help. Please also point out if there is anything wrong with my code so that I can improve in my future exercises :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove this line it will work

```
job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
```

You use reducer as combiner but your reducer read IntWritable and write FloatWritable.
And the following happens:

1. Mapper write IntWritable.
2. Combiner read IntWritable and write FloatWritable.
3. Reducer tries to read IntWritable, but takes FloatWritable and throws exceptions.